# BSA calculation results me Zero

Tags: java

```
public static int calculateBSA(double height, double grams) {
    double weightforBmi = convertGramsToPounds(grams);
    return (int) Math.sqrt(((convertCentimeterToInches(height) * weightforBmi) / 3131));
}
```

Here is my code for converting Centimeter to Inches and Grams to Pounds.

```
private static double convertCentimeterToInches(double height) {
    return (Math.round((height / 2.54) * 100) / 100);
}

public static int convertGramsToPounds(double grams) {
   double gramsToPoundUnit = .00220462262;
   double pounds = (grams * gramsToPoundUnit);
   return (int)(Math.round(pounds * 100) / 100);
}
```

BSA calculation results me always `Zero`. Am i doing the Math.sqrt rightly inside BSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call

> calculateBSA(1e4, 1e4)

it returns 5. For relative small values of grams convertGramsToPounds(double grams) returns 0 because you casted it to an int. Similar happens with the calculateBSA and convertCentimeterToInches methods. If you can accept double values one can modify the code as:

```
public double calculateBSA(double height, double grams) {
    double weightforBmi = convertGramsToPounds(grams);
    return  Math.sqrt(((convertCentimeterToInches(height) * weightforBmi) / 3131));
}

private double convertCentimeterToInches(double height) {
    return (height / 2.54);
}

public double convertGramsToPounds(double grams) {
    double gramsToPoundUnit = .00220462262;
    double pounds = (grams * gramsToPoundUnit);
    return pounds;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the methods `calculateBSA` & `convertGramsToPounds` return `double` and not `int`. Since your `double gramsToPoundUnit = .00220462262;` is less than 1, then the cast to `int` is returning `0`, which is causing the problem.

Also, since you've such a small value there(`gramsToPoundUnit`), the `grams` value you pass to `calculateBSA` better be a big one to get some proper results!

E.g:- After the changes mentioned above are done,

> calculateBSA(103.2, 5000.4) gives 0.37487355474941564

Answer (score 1):

If either one of the calculations that get cast to ints are less than one you'll get zero as the result.